# What does 어느 in 화창한 어느 아침 means?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, meaning

I have googled to see what does 어느 mean and what I understand is that it is used to ask questions. I am confused what does it mean in the above sentence.

Please also explain the sentence structure used in above sentence so that I can use it to make sentences by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

어느 in your phrase means "one" or "a certain", referring to something introduced first.
It can also mean "which" or "whichever" in a question, or "(not) any/either" when treating all candidates the same way.

- 어느 것이 더 좋아? = Which one do you like better?  (question)
- 어느 것도 마음에 안 들어 = I don't like any or them.  (negative sentence)
- 어느 멋진 날 = one fine day.  (introducing one particular case)

Most Korean question words (like WH-words in English) work like this.

- 언제 올 거야? = When are you coming? (question)
- 언제든지 괜찮아 = Any time is good (treating all cases the same, like "any".
- 언제 한 번 와 = Come over sometime (referring to a a certain case, like "a" or "some".

---

- 어떻게 할 거야? = What are you going to do?
- 어떻게 해도 안 돼. = It won't work no matter what I do.
- 어떻게 해 봐. = Do something if you can.

---

- 누가 그렇게 말해? = Who is saying that?
- 누구나 다 그래 = Everyone is saying that / Everyone is like that.
- 누군가가 도와줬으면 좋겠다 = I hope someone can help me.